# what are the prerequisites/background needed to understanding Amari's "Information geometry and its applications"?

Tags: information-geometry

Someone suggested Shun-ichi Amari's book "Information geometry and its applications", because they said it deeply explains some topic we were discussing.

I've tried reading it and found it extremely bewildering; I have some math background and can usually get through textbooks, but I'm very stuck with this one.

I took some time to learn some basics of differential geometry, but found that it doesn't really clear up the confusion. I've learned some probability/stats in the past, but so far (I'm having trouble even in Chapter 1), that isn't really the bottleneck either.

My question is, is there some other subfield that I should learn about, such that this book will be more understandable?